# use of the [<- operator to modify a line of data

Tags: r, matrix

I have some data

```
data <- diag(5)
```

I want to use the `[<-` operator to change a line.

The result should be:

```
data[1,] <- 2 

> data
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

I know I can do e.g.

```
`[<-`(data, i=1, j=3, 2)
```

which gives

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    8    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

but how can I operate on line (or column, same issue)?

I tried `j=NULL`, `j=integer(0)`, it doesn't work. I could do `j=1:5` and get what I want but I am wondering how to mimic `data[1,] <- 2` and not `data[1,1:5] <- 2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> `[<-`(data, 1, , 2)   # blank 2nd argument
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: I believe this is basically what `data[1,] <- 2` is parsed to. See also section 3.4.4 of the [language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment).

Comment: I can't believe that this line is valid R: `\`[<-\`(data, i=1, j= , value=2)`! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @antoine-sac See `help("missing")`.

Comment: @Roland I use `missing` on a daily basis! But I would write `f(a=1, c=3)` not `f(a=1, b=, c=3)`. I think the syntax is chocking to any programmer coming from another language :) Thanks for your link to the language definition btw, very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ncol` to ensure that all columns are set:

```
`[<-`(data, i = 1, j = 1:ncol(data), 2)
```